# Create simple database for chess tournaments

Tags: sql, database, chess

I am trying to make simple app for chess tournaments, but I have problem with database, I have users that participate in tournament (thats fine) but how do I give users to the round and match, should i make another relations user_tournament-round-tournament, user_tournament-match-round?
[image]

Comment: Can users take part in a tournament without playing any match? If no, then link them to the matches not to the tournaments.

Comment: In your schema you've missed the link between user and round and/or match

Comment: @stickybit user register to tournament, tournaments have rounds and each round have matches.

Comment: @sadge_user: That doesn't really answer my question and shows that your case isn't a simple one and thus the problem with such "Help me make my data model" questions which is that they're typically too broad for SO, unless it is a specific question about a specific design decision. They would require detailed knowledge about what should be modeled in the real world where even a small scope typically raises a lot of questions during the design process. And SO is designed as a Q & A platform and not for such interactive processes.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answers a food for though rather than a solution. In your question there is not enough information to fully cover all use cases, so the answer below contains a lot of speculation.

In my over simplistic view and picking up on your initial model, the `tournament_competitors` (renaming from `user_tournament` as we have competitors and not users) table would create a unique id for each enrolled competitor. This id would be used as a reference in a `tournament_matches` table (the table would link twice to the `tournament_competitors` this table would connect two opponents - constraint warning). The table would also register the match type.

For the match type, I see two possibilities.
The matches table would list all possible match types (final, semi-final, quarter-final, elimination rounds, etc.) and these would be referred to in the `tournament_matches` table via id (composite key in the form `tournament_id-competitor_id-group_id`). This approach, specially for the elimination round matches, requires the need to find a way to link the number of competitors in each elimination group with then number of matches each competitor has to through before they are considered eliminated or not - creating a round number. I see this as a business logic part so not on the DB. The `group_id` also needs to be calculated and it would be best done on the application.

The alternative is to have the various match types in the `tournament_matches` table as a free field - populated by the application. The tournament structure (Number of Groups, number of opponents in each group, etc.) would be defined as attributes in the `tournaments` table. In this view there is no need for the `rounds` table.